# What is the cost per level progression in the game?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm currently at 61 levels and my cost of building a new level is over 520K credits.

Is there a fixed amount the cost goes up by or is it a progression?  Admittedly I haven't been paying enough attention. Sometimes it seems to go up a few thousand, others 10s of thousands per level.

I'm asking because I may want to complete all the imperial levels, and can't decide if it's worth doing earlier in the game because of cost. Or, is it worth building levels that generate more income due and will finance the construction of those levels later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values for floors don't start according to a formula until you get to floor 12, which costs 12,150.  Once you reach that floor, the formula is:

150 * (Floor # - 3) * (Floor # - 3)

So, for floor 12 (which is actually the 10th floor you build) , you'd come up with: 150 * 9 * 9 = 12,150

For floor 83, you'd come up with 150 * 80 * 80 = 960,000

I've verified this formula works for all floors from 12 to 83.  Floors 3 through 11 appear to be random in how costs are calculated.

Also, random factoid, the amount of the increase increases by 300 for each level (after 12).  So going from 12 (12,150) to 13 (15,000) is a 2,850 increase.  Going from 13 (15,000) to 14 (18,150) is a 3,150 increase, which is the 2,850 (from 12->13) + 300.

Going from 14 (18,150) to 15 (21,600) increases by 3,150 + 300 for a total of 3,450.

I'm sure that's just a function of math in the original formula, but I thought it was a neat pattern.

As requested, here is a graph of the costs:

[image: graph]

Here are the values for each floor and how long it takes to build:

**Floor    |   Hours   |   Coins**

Floor 1 |   N/A |   N/A

Floor 2 |   N/A |   N/A

Floor 3 |   N/A |   100

Floor 4 |   0.066   |   200

Floor 5 |   0.1 |   500

Floor 6 |   0.2 |   650

Floor 7 |   0   |   1,000

Floor 8 |   0.5 |   1,650

Floor 9 |   1   |   3,150

Floor 10    |   1.5 |   4,400

Floor 11    |   2   |   8,600

Floor 12    |   2.5 |   12,150

Floor 13    |   3   |   15,000

Floor 14    |   3.5 |   18,150

Floor 15    |   4   |   21,600

Floor 16    |   4.5 |   25,350

Floor 17    |   5   |   29,400

Floor 18    |   5.5 |   33,750

Floor 19    |   6   |   38,400

Floor 20    |   6.5 |   43,350

Floor 21    |   7   |   48,600

Floor 22    |   7.5 |   54,150

Floor 23    |   8   |   60,000

Floor 24    |   8.5 |   66,150

Floor 25    |   9   |   72,600

Floor 26    |   9.5 |   79,350

Floor 27    |   10  |   86,400

Floor 28    |   10.5    |   93,750

Floor 29    |   11  |   101,400

Floor 30    |   11.5    |   109,350

Floor 31    |   12  |   117,600

Floor 32    |   12.5    |   126,150

Floor 33    |   13  |   135,000

Floor 34    |   13.5    |   144,150

Floor 35    |   14  |   153,600

Floor 36    |   14.5    |   163,350

Floor 37    |   15  |   173,400

Floor 38    |   15.5    |   183,750

Floor 39    |   16  |   194,400

Floor 40    |   16.5    |   205,350

Floor 41    |   17  |   216,600

Floor 42    |   17.5    |   228,150

Floor 43    |   18  |   240,000

Floor 44    |   18.5    |   252,150

Floor 45    |   19  |   264,600

Floor 46    |   19.5    |   277,350

Floor 47    |   20  |   290,400

Floor 48    |   20.5    |   303,750

Floor 49    |   21  |   317,400

Floor 50    |   21.5    |   331,350

Floor 51    |   22  |   345,600

Floor 52    |   22.5    |   360,150

Floor 53    |   23  |   375,000

Floor 54    |   23.5    |   390,150

Floor 55    |   24  |   405,600

Floor 56    |   24.5    |   421,350

Floor 57    |   25  |   437,400

Floor 58    |   25.5    |   453,750

Floor 59    |   26  |   470,400

Floor 60    |   26.5    |   487,350

Floor 61    |   27  |   504,600

Floor 62    |   27.5    |   522,150

Floor 63    |   28  |   540,000

Floor 64    |   28.5    |   558,150

Floor 65    |   29  |   576,600

Floor 66    |   29.5    |   595,350

Floor 67    |   30  |   614,400

Floor 68    |   30.5    |   633,750

Floor 69    |   31  |   653,400

Floor 70    |   31.5    |   673,350

Floor 71    |   32  |   693,600

Floor 72    |   32.5    |   714,150

Floor 73    |   33  |   735,000

Floor 74    |   33.5    |   756,150

Floor 75    |   34  |   777,600

Floor 76    |   34.5    |   799,350

Floor 77    |   35  |   821,400

Floor 78    |   35.5    |   843,750

Floor 79    |   36  |   866,400

Floor 80    |   36.5    |   889,350

Floor 81    |   37  |   912,600

Floor 82    |   37.5    |   936,150

Floor 83    |   38  |   960,000

Comment: This data would be better presented in a graph, like the existing answer has done.

Comment: @RBF Welcome to Arqade. You are off to a great start!  Please take the suggestion above and present this as a graph, too.

Comment: nice work, i'm just curious as to where you obtained the data though

Comment: I made a spreadsheet and manually logged the cost and time for each floor built.

Answer (score 4):

I've plotted a couple points to an excel spreadsheet and the price for new levels seems to follow this function:

```
y = 150x² - 350x + 875
```

where `y` is the price for a new level and `x` is the total number of levels minus 1

**Note:** I've assumed that this is a quadratic function because no other other functions or polynomials seem to fit as well as a quadratic.
Also, for some odd reason, excel insists that the vertex lies well within the first quadrant when we all agree that this is likely not the case, we simply need more points for a better analysis.

***Current R² = 1***

*an* `R²` *of* `1` *is indicative that this is not enough data!*

---

[image]

The most optimal way for building all imperial levels is definitely to go with the income-generating levels before building imperial levels.

Keep in mind that this is only a speculation based on a *very* small data-set. If anybody has more points to contribute, please do.

**I have only used these points for this regression:**

```
1  1000
15 25350
41 228000
42 240000
61 522150
62 540000
63 558150
64 576600
65 595350 - Imperial Lvl Added
```

---

*This data-set needs more points, I've changed the level number to `current level - 1` because this is how an array is set up in programming.*

Comment: @DavidM You are correct, this is only a speculation, I've edited my response with a new equation that may be more accurate

Comment: @DavidM thanks for the support David! but to get the best possible fit, i would need more data! This function is **far** from perfect, but i think it's a decent start to an estimation as to what the actual function is!

Comment: Doesn't work for me here, I've got 15 levels currently and my cost to add a new one is 25,350.  Current formula gives 43,125 for my case.  Hope an extra data point helps :)

Comment: It's also possible that the price changes depending on what levels have been built *i.e. building imperials don't increase the price as much as standard levels*

Comment: So i'm 100% positive that if this is indeed a polynomial, the first constant is 150, it's the other two that are troublesome, the second constant should be zero, or at the least, positive. More points from the earlier levels would be nice!

Comment: Just a thought … what if it's not a formula. What if it goes up by the total amount of credit that can be produced by the level you just built … and a fixed amount for an Imperial level.

Comment: @DavidM this thought has crossed my mind as well, however the amount that it goes up is not fixed. It changes each time you add a level. It is possible that there really isn't a formula that the app uses and that it is simply incrementations based on some arbitrary value. However i tested this type of function as well (exponential) and the results don't fit very well.

Comment: Deleted a bunch of my comments to satisfy the automated gods. Perhaps u should do the same @char1es